# Why do I get an error when trying to make an associated token account via anchor?

Tags: anchor, program

```
        let create_cpi_accounts = associated_token::Create {
            payer: ctx.accounts.user.to_account_info(),
            associated_token: ctx.accounts.wallet.to_account_info(),
            authority: ctx.accounts.mint_authority.to_account_info(),
            mint: ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
            system_program: ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
            token_program: ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
        };
        let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new(
            ctx.accounts.token_program.clone().to_account_info(),
            create_cpi_accounts,
        );
        associated_token::create(cpi_ctx)?;
```

Gives me the following error:

```
     Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: An account required by the instruction is missing
```

What is causing this? Everything seems to line up with the [documentation](https://docs.rs/anchor-spl/latest/anchor_spl/associated_token/struct.Create.html) and I am passing all the correct accounts.

Comment: can you add the rest of the instruction, the accounts, and how you're invoking the instruction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a [Solana Playground](https://beta.solpg.io/https://github.com/solana-developers/anchor-examples/tree/main/account-constraints/associated_token) example for how to create an associated token account in an Anchor program.

```
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use anchor_spl::{
    associated_token::AssociatedToken,
    token::{Mint, Token, TokenAccount},
};

declare_id!("BQJrDLm7z8NPnE45oNLfWXDzudhBHSDWTsKadxmU4FYE");

#[program]
pub mod example {
    use super::*;

    pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>) -> Result<()> {
        msg!(
            "Created Associated Token Account: {}",
            ctx.accounts.associated_token.key()
        );
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(
        init,
        payer = signer,
        associated_token::mint = mint,
        associated_token::authority = signer,
    )]
    pub associated_token: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    pub mint: Account<'info, Mint>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    pub associated_token_program: Program<'info, AssociatedToken>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```

And here is how to you invoke the instruction

```
import * as anchor from "@coral-xyz/anchor";
import { Program } from "@coral-xyz/anchor";
import { Example } from "../target/types/example";
import {
  createMint,
  getAccount,
  getAssociatedTokenAddressSync,
} from "@solana/spl-token";
import assert from "assert";

describe("example", () => {
  const provider = anchor.AnchorProvider.env();
  anchor.setProvider(provider);
  const wallet = provider.wallet as anchor.Wallet;
  const connection = provider.connection;

  const program = anchor.workspace.Example as Program<Example>;

  it("Is initialized!", async () => {
    // Create new mint account
    const mint = await createMint(
      connection,
      wallet.payer, // payer
      wallet.publicKey, // mint authority
      null, // freeze authority
      2 // decimals
    );

    // Derive associated token account address
    const associatedTokenAddress = getAssociatedTokenAddressSync(
      mint,
      wallet.publicKey
    );

    // Create associated token account via a cross program invocation (CPI)
    const transactionSignature = await program.methods
      .initialize()
      .accounts({
        signer: wallet.publicKey,
        associatedToken: associatedTokenAddress,
        mint: mint,
      })
      .rpc();

    console.log("Your transaction signature", transactionSignature);

    const tokenAccount = await getAccount(connection, associatedTokenAddress);
    assert(tokenAccount.mint.toBase58() == mint.toBase58());
    assert(tokenAccount.owner.toBase58() == wallet.publicKey.toBase58());
  });
});
```